# Which chart can I use to create XY range chart with D3.js like Blood Pressure Chart

Tags: d3.js, charts, bar-chart, data-visualization, nvd3.js

I want to create a chart like one given here
http://www.bloodpressureuk.org/BloodPressureandyou/Thebasics/Bloodpressurechart
using D3.js utilizing existing libraries or any other HTML5 javascript libraries. UI seems to be similar to Treemap chart but it doesn't have plotting capabilities. And I want a movable plot also to select X,Y coordinates. Please suggest which charting library to use.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a similar chart using the ZingChart javascript charting library. It can render in HTML5 Canvas.

http://zingchart.com/playground/run/53c402eb868c5

Initially thought about using a piano chart/treemap as you suggested. But what made the most sense was actually to use an area chart with stepped aspect for the colored blood pressure zones. Then I applied a scatter chart on top to plot blood pressure numbers. This approach could work for you in other charting libraries as well.

The plots could be made draggable with the node dragging plugin- http://www.zingchart.com/playground/presentation/category/4/ But I wasn't sure your request for selecting x/y coordinates and moving them would apply to the blood pressure use case.

I'm on the ZingChart team, so feel free to reach out if you have any questions about this demo.